# How to use google exo player in android project that has a minimum sdk of 9?

Tags: android, exoplayer

I want to use `google exoplayer` in my project.But my project's `minimum sdk is 9`.
how can I use the `google exoplayer` library in my project?
Thanks!

Comment: My guess is that you can't. Quoting their `build.gradle` file comment: "ExoPlayer specifies a minSdkVersion of 9 because various components provided by the library may be of use on older devices. However, please note that the core media playback functionality provided by the library requires API level 16 or greater." I assume that you are seeking to use what ExoPlayer defines as "core media playback functionality", and most likely it uses Android APIs that were added in API Level 16.

Comment: @CommonsWare thanks for your answer.

Comment: @CommonsWare do you know any other media player library for android?

Comment: For API Level 9, the only choice that I know of are the native ones (e.g., `MediaPlayer`, `SoundPool`) and possibly [libVLC](https://github.com/mrmaffen/vlc-android-sdk).

Comment: @CommonsWare thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately you can't.

ExoPlayer is based on the Android Codec APIs. These are available starting with API 16. If you need CENC DRM (content protection) this is supported starting with API 19.

Please also refer to the ExoPlayer Developer Guide. Specifically the page '[Supported Devices](https://google.github.io/ExoPlayer/supported-devices.html)' which gives you more details.